# Of two rows eliminate the one with more NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-munging

I am looking for a way to check wether two columns in a data frame contain the same elements for one or more rows, then eliminate the row containing more NAs.

Lets assume we have a data frame as such:

```
x <- data.frame("Year" = c(2017,2017,2017,2018,2018),
            "Country" = c("Sweden", "Sweden", "Norway", "Denmark", "Finland"),
            "Sales" = c(15, 15, 18, 13, 12),
            "Campaigns" = c(3, NA, 4, 1, 1),
            "Employees" = c(15, 15, 12, 8, 9),
            "Satisfaction" = c(0.8, NA, 0.9, 0.95, 0.87),
            "Expenses" = c(NA, NA, 9000, 7500, 4300))
```

Note that the entry for Sweden in the year 2017 is there twice, but the first row has one entry with NA while the other one contains NAs in three places. Now I would like to check wether two rows contain the same "Year" and "Country", then proceed to eliminate the row containing the higher amount of NAs, in this case the second row. I did some research but I could not seem to find a solution for this particular case.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you add your desired output?

Comment: Friedemann, if one of the answers meets your needs, please "accept" it (one only) by selecting the checkmark to the left of it (optionally up-vote any or all that you find useful).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I tested the solutions and they all worked for me. I have accepted the solution using dplyr as it is the most elegant for me, but thats just subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  mutate(n_na = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>%  ## calculate NAs for each row      
  group_by(Year, Country) %>%           ## for each year/country
  arrange(n_na) %>%                       ## sort by number of NAs
  slice(1) %>%                            ## take the first row
  select(-n_na)                           ## remove the NA counter column
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   Year, Country [4]
   Year Country Sales Campaigns Employees Satisfaction Expenses
  <dbl>  <fctr> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1  2017  Norway    18         4        12         0.90     9000
2  2017  Sweden    15         3        15         0.80       NA
3  2018 Denmark    13         1         8         0.95     7500
4  2018 Finland    12         1         9         0.87     4300
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use a data.table approach

```
library(data.table)
ind <-  setDT(x)[,  {
     i1 <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, is.na))
    .I[i1 > 0 & (i1 == max(i1))]
    }, .(Year, Country)]$V1
x[-ind]
#    Year Country Sales Campaigns Employees Satisfaction Expenses
#1: 2017  Sweden    15         3        15         0.80       NA
#2: 2017  Norway    18         4        12         0.90     9000
#3: 2018 Denmark    13         1         8         0.95     7500
#4: 2018 Finland    12         1         9         0.87     4300
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
x$nas <- rowSums(sapply(x, is.na))
do.call(rbind,
        by(x, x[c("Year","Country")],
           function(df) head(df[order(df$nas),,drop=FALSE], n=1)))
#   Year Country Sales Campaigns Employees Satisfaction Expenses nas
# 4 2018 Denmark    13         1         8         0.95     7500   0
# 5 2018 Finland    12         1         9         0.87     4300   0
# 3 2017  Norway    18         4        12         0.90     9000   0
# 1 2017  Sweden    15         3        15         0.80       NA   1
```

Not too surprisingly, the `data.table` implementation is the fast, though I"m a little surprised by how much faster it was than base R. Being a small dataset could affect this. (In the benchmarking, I had to create a copy of the original, since `data.table` modifies the data in-place, so `x` is no longer a `data.frame`.)

```
microbenchmark(
  data.table = {
    x0 <- copy(x)
    ind <-  setDT(x0)[,  {
      i1 <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, is.na))
      .I[i1 > 0 & (i1 == max(i1))]
    }, .(Year, Country)]$V1
    x0[-ind]
  },
  dplyr = {
    x %>%
      mutate(n_na = rowSums(is.na(.))) %>%  ## calculate NAs for each row      
      group_by(Year, Country) %>%           ## for each year/country
      arrange(n_na) %>%                       ## sort by number of NAs
      slice(1) %>%                            ## take the first row
      select(-n_na)                           ## remove the NA counter column
  },
  base = {
    x0 <- x
    x0$nas <- rowSums(sapply(x0, is.na))
    do.call(rbind,
            by(x0, x0[c("Year","Country")],
               function(df) head(df[order(df$nas),,drop=FALSE], n=1)))
  }
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#  data.table 1.223477 1.441005 1.973714 1.582861 1.919090 12.837569   100
#       dplyr 2.675239 2.901882 4.465172 3.079295 3.806453 42.261540   100
#        base 2.039615 2.209187 2.737758 2.298714 2.570760  8.586946   100
```